# How to unit test a JS function that receives a select element with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to unit test the following JS function:

```
let convert = {};

convert.f = function f(element)
{
    options = Array.from(element.options);
    options.forEach(function (item, index) {
        item.removeAttribute('selected');
    });
}

module.exports = convert;
```

which is expected to receive a select DOM element and remove the selected attribute to its options.

I am currently testing it using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) using following test code:

```
let convert = require('../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/js/helper.js')

var assert = require('assert');

describe('Function', function() {
  describe('#f()', function() {
    it('should work', function() {
      var selectedOption = [{}]
      var options = [{}]
      var element = { className: '', tag: 't', name:'a', id:'b', selectedOptions: selectedOption, options: options };
      convert.f(element);
    });
  });
});
```

Currently I am getting "TypeError: item.removeAttribute is not a function". I am already aware it is not the right approach so I need help to understand the best way to unit test the code. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock `select` element object containing an array of options where each option has following:

- property named `selected`, this property will be true for the option that has `selected` attribute on it
- `removeAttribute` function

`select` element object should look like this

```
const removeAttr = function() {
    this.selected = false;
};

const select = {
    options: [
      { selected: true, value: 1, removeAttribute: removeAttr  },
      { selected: true, value: 1, removeAttribute: removeAttr  },
      { selected: true, value: 1, removeAttribute: removeAttr  },
    ]
};
```

See this [demo](https://repl.it/repls/GlitteringPersonalVolume). Open the shell and run `npm test` command. I have used `chai` as assertion library in this demo.

To open the shell, on a mac, press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. On windows, press the `?` icon at the bottom right corner and click on keyboard shortcuts option from the menu.